# Update ListView with cursor and SimpleCursorAdapter

Tags: android, sqlite, listview, cursor

My cursor is fetch data from sqlite.

```
msgsdbadapter = new MSGSDBAdapter(this);
msgsdbadapter.open();
cons_cursor = msgsdbadapter.fetchConversations();
startManagingCursor(cons_cursor);
```

After that I create a SimpleCursorAdapter and assign it to ListView. The ListView now can display some records well.

```
String[] from = new String[] { MSGSDBAdapter.KEY_FROM, MSGSDBAdapter.KEY_MSG, MSGSDBAdapter.KEY_DATE};
int[] to = new int[] { R.id.lblFrom, R.id.lblMsgExcerpt, R.id.lblDate };
cons_cursor_adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(context, R.layout.conversation_item, cons_cursor, from, to);
lvConversations.setAdapter(cons_cursor_adapter);
```

Next, I insert new row into table and notify dataset changed, but the ListView is not update

```
msgsdbadapter.createMsg(msg);
cons_cursor_adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

And when I should close the db connection?

Comment: No need to close it before onDestroy

Comment: I think u need to update cursor that u have passed to adapter.

Comment: How to update cursor? I can create new cursor and assign it again to adapter. But that way seem bad?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to either `requery()` the existing `Cursor`, or run the query again to get a fresh `Cursor` and swap the new `Cursor` into your `CursorAdapter`.

Comment: requery is decaperpted. Are there have a new approach for this problem?

Comment: @complez: Run the query again to get a fresh `Cursor` and swap the new `Cursor` into your `CursorAdapter` using `changeCursor()`.

Comment: This updated solution works just fine, but I'm wondering why the `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` is not able to do this itself?

Answer (score 0):

The best solution if your using the ListFragment is to put this in inside this sample:

```
 public SimpleCursorAdapter myNote;
    public class NOteLIST_MAIN extends ListFragment {

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        myNote.getCursor().requery();//Don't forget to put these on onResume }

    private void DataLoader(){private void DataFiller(){
          myNote = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.notes_row_line, notesCursor, from, to,0);
          setListAdapter(myNote);}  
}
```